# Writing an action using LWC that accesses the records selected in a custom object tab list

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view, tab, lightning-quickaction

LWCs that are hooked up as buttons on record pages are working fine for me with:

```
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
```

both headlessly - `<actionType>Action</actionType>` - and with a modal - `<actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>`.

But I'm struggling to figure out how to create an LWC-based action for a custom object tab that shows a list of the records of a custom object. I'm assuming that this is appropriate:

```
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
```

but specifically want the action to detect the records selected in the list e.g. 2 and 3 in the image below. Note that the list here is not a custom `lightning-datatable` but rather a standard platform list.

Is there a way to get that selection information in the LWC?

[image: list view checkboxes]

(In ancient Visualforce there was `GETRECORDIDS` and in more recent Visualforce the `StandardController` would have the Id values. But in LWC? Any progress from [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233046/getrecordidsobjecttype-testobject-c-in-lightning-component)?)